# redirigir pagina html cuando se intenta ingresar desde el navegador

Tags: javascript, html, css

Necesito evitar que ingrese a una dirección html, es decir si alguien intenta ingresar desde el navegador, este lo dirija a la pagina principal. En cambio, que solo sea posible acceder desde la pagina principal.

Quisiera hacerlo desde htaccess, mi js es el siguiente

```
    $(".accept").click(function (event) {
  var counter = 0;
  $(".accept").each(function(key, checkbox) {
    if(checkbox.checked == false) {
      $("#purchase-continue").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      return false;
    } else {
      counter++;
      if(counter == $(".accept").length) {
        $("#purchase-continue").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    }
  });
});

$('#buy-token').on("#modal.close", function(event, modal) {
$(".accept").prop('checked', false);
$("#purchase-continue").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

$("#purchase-continue").click(function() {
    switch($(this).attr("data-source")) {
        case "more-information":
            top.location.href = "information.html";
            break;

        case "buy":
            top.location.href = "instructions.html";
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Eso lo tienes que hacer con PHP, usar variables de sesión y redireccionamientos en caso de que no existan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914477/php-if-session-is-started-redirect-to-a-different-page

Comment: No se puede hacer desde front-end, tienes que hacerlo desde el lado de servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto lo puedes conseguir leyendo el valor del [`referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).

`document.referrer` devolverá una cadena con la URL de la página que redirigió a la página actual. Si no se accedió a la página a través de un enlace (p.e. escribiendo la URL en la barra de direcciones directamente o a través de un marcador) su valor será una cadena vacía.

Entonces en JS podrías añadir algo como esto, que comprueba si el referrer es tu página principal, y si no, redirige a ella:

```
if (document.referrer != URL_DE_TU_PAGINA_PRINCIPAL) {
    window.location.href = URL_DE_TU_PAGINA_PRINCIPAL;
}
```

> **AVISO**: aunque este método va a funcionar, **sería mejor hacer una comprobación similar en el lado del servidor** porque el usuario podría deshabilitar JavaScript en su navegador o editarlo para quitar esa redirección y entonces se saltaría tu comprobación.