# redirigir pagina si se ingresa desde url

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

que tal soy nuevo en esto y necesito redirigir una pagina html si se intenta ingresar desde el navegador, es decir si alguien intenta ingresar a www.ejemplo.com/instrucciones, no sea posible pero que si sea posible desde mi pagina principal, validando una información, estoy intentando hacerlo desde htacces

algo tipo

```
if(checkbox==true){
top.location.href = "www.ejemplo.com/instructions.html";
}
else{www.ejemplo.com}
```

Comment: Parece que la diferencia con tu [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114503/250) es que quieres hacerlo en el lado del servidor usando .htaccess. ¿Es eso correcto? Si lo es, deberías editar la pregunta para clarificarlo y etiquetarla mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo sugeriría usar `document.referrer`, si se llegó a tu página `instrucciones.html` usando la barra de direcciones o desde un marcador, entonces será un `string` vacío, de lo contrario (mediante un link) tendría que contener la `URL` de la página que ha enlazado dicho sitio, te doy un ejemplo:

instrucciones.html

```
if(document.referrer == ''){
    //Podrías redirigir a la página principal
    window.location.href = 'http://www.ejemplo.com';
}
else{
    //Si no se llegó a 'instrucciones.html' desde la barra de direcciones
    //Podrías verificar de qué página la trajo aquí
    if(document.referrer == 'http://www.ejemplo.com'){
        //Si se accedió desde tu página principal
    }
    else{
       //En caso que no, podrías redirigir a tu página principal, o mandarlos atrás usando 'history.back()'
        window.location.href = 'http://www.ejemplo.com';
    }
}
```

Espero y te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Manda un parametro en la url por ejemplo
en tu pagina 1 desde pagina principal
www.ejemplo.com/instructions.html?accesso=1

con java script lo validas

```
var url_string = window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("accesso");
// Valida si el parametro viene en la url si no viene lo manda a la pagina principal
if (!c){
  window.location.href = "/"
}
```

Caso desde el navegador al entrar directo a la url no lleva el parametro por el cual lo enviara a la pagina principal

Comment: ¿Cómo impediría esto que el usuario pusiera `www.ejemplo.com/instructions.html?accesso=1` directamente en la barra de navegación?

Comment: y no puedes , pero el usuario no es adivino que esto sea asi  , podrias pocer un string enorme aunque nose para que quieres impedir eso

Answer (score 1):

En .htaccess podrías añadir algo como esto:

> Aclaración: no he podido probar esta solución y podría contener errores

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !http://www.ejemplo.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/instructions.html$ http://www.ejemplo.com [L,R]
```

Lo que hace línea a línea:

1. Activa el motor de redireccionamiento y reescritura.
2. Comprueba la cabecera HTTP_REFERER para ver si es http://www.ejemplo.com (exactamente esa URL, la de la página principal).
3. Si la URL es instructions.html (y no venía de la página principal, condición de la línea anterior), entonces redirige a la página principal  http://www.ejemplo.com.

---

Un problema de esta solución es que la cabecera HTTP_REFERER no es fiable: algunos navegadores no la mandan y un usuario con conocimientos podría modificarla y enviarla confundiendo al servidor.

Comment: Detalle: ojo que el segundo parámetro de `RewriteCond` es un regex. Si bien en este caso prácticamente no influye, los puntos coinciden con cualquier caracter. Personalmente lo modificaría a algo como `!^https?://www\.ejemplo\.com(?:/|$)`. Además, en el `RewriteRule` conviene redireccionar a `/` en vez de a todo el dominio calificado (así se evitan problemas si algún día se implementa SSL por ejemplo).

Answer (score 0):

La solución de @luisdmz es la más práctica y sencilla, te recomiendo esa. Otra solución puede ser usar `localStorage`. Cuando se haga click en el enlace **instrucciones** pon una bandera de modo que ni buen dicha página esté cargando, verificas si la bandera existe y en caso de no existir, haces un redirect o vuelves a donde estaba mediante `history.back()`.

En la página `index.html`:

```
const instructions = document.getElementById('#instructions');
instructions.addEventListener('click', function() {
  localStorage.setItem('navigationValid', flag);
});
```

En la página `instructions.html`

```
const navigationValid = Boolean(localStorage.getItem('navigationValid'));
if (!navigationValid) {
  history.back();
}
localStorage.removeItem('navigationValid');
```

En lugar de un parámetro con un nombre deducible puedes usar un hash para que el usuario no pueda poner el parámetro en la URL o en el storage.