# Como negar acceso a una pagina sin que antes pase por inicio?

Tags: php

¿Cómo hago que un usuario no ingrese a una ruta sin antes pasar por el inicio?

ejemplo:

```
public_html/proyecto/pagina_contenido.html
```

Necesito que antes de que entre a esa página esté obligado a pasar por:

```
public_html/proyecto/inicio.html
```

para eventualmente desde `inicio.html` ser redireccionado a la página con contenido.

Comment: Podrías restringir la entrada a dicha página con variables de sesión, las conoces ? Te invito a que hagas el [tour] para que sepas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla, daludos !

Comment: Posible duplicado de [redirigir pagina si se ingresa desde url](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/115422/250) o [redirigir pagina html cuando se intenta ingresar desde el navegador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114503/250). La idea final es la misma: redirigir a la página de inicio si no se ha llegado a esa página desde el inicio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para controlar el acceso lo más recomendable es manejar el acceso mediante sesiones.

en tu archivo `pagina_contenido.php` buscas la variable de sesión, si no tiene valor, rediriges a `inicio.php` con el encabezado apropiado.

inicio.php

```
//Primera línea siempre
session_start();
//en algún momento guardas la variable de sesión 
$_SESSION['registrado'] = true;
```

pagina_contenido.php

```
if(!$_SESSION['registrado']){
   //encabezado de redirección
   header("location:inicio.php");
   die;
}
```